# remove trailing slash from hyperlink href

Tags: php, hyperlink, preg-replace, trim

This is pretty much the same information as a previous post of mine, but is a different question.

I have a variable of `$this->post['message']` which is whatever the user posts.

If the user posts:

```
Check out this vine https://vine.co/v/iF20jKHvnqg/
```

Once submitted the html output looks like:

```
Check out this vine <a href="https://vine.co/v/iF20jKHvnqg/" target="_blank">https://vine.co/v/iF20jKHvnqg/</a>
```

and that is what `$this->post['message']` is equal to.

So in my back end I have created a plugin

```
$drc_embed_vine =  '<iframe src="https://vine.co/v/$2/embed/simple" width="480" height="480" frameborder="0"></iframe>';

$this->post['message'] = preg_replace('~(<a href="https?://vine.co)/v/(.*)" target="_blank">(https?://vine.co)/v/(.*)<\/a>~', $drc_embed_vine, $this->post['message']);
```

This finds vine links in posts and converts them to the an iframe.  I'm facing an issue with the end slash though.

If a user posts `https://vine.co/v/iF20jKHvnqg` which once submitted turns into `<a href="https://vine.co/v/iF20jKHvnqg" target="_blank">https://vine.co/v/iF20jKHvnqg</a>` it gets converted to an iframe fine.

But if the user posts `https://vine.co/v/iF20jKHvnqg/` which changes to `<a href="https://vine.co/v/iF20jKHvnqg/" target="_blank">https://vine.co/v/iF20jKHvnqg/</a>` it does not get converted.  The difference being the trailing slash.

Now I have tried:

```
$this->post['message'] = rtrim($this->post['message'],"/");

$drc_embed_vine =  '<iframe src="https://vine.co/v/$2/embed/simple" width="480" height="480" frameborder="0"></iframe>';

$this->post['message'] = preg_replace('~(<a href="https?://vine.co)/v/(.*)" target="_blank">(https?://vine.co)/v/(.*)<\/a>~', $drc_embed_vine, $this->post['message']);
```

But that doesn't seem to work, is there a way I can target vine links inside of `$this->post['message']` and remove the trailing slash, or even remove the trailing slash from any link inside `$this->post['message']`

So if

```
$this->post['message'] = 'Go to <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/" target="_blank">http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/</a>';
```

It would become

```
$this->post['message'] = 'Go to <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask" target="_blank">http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask</a>';
```

I'm mainly focused on the Vine links at the moment but if it is possible to do for all links that may work out better in the long run.

**My latest failed attempt (I'm still trying to figure this out)**

```
$drc_embed_vine =  '<iframe src="https://vine.co/v/$2/embed/simple" width="480" height="480" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
$str = $this->post['message'];
$str = rtrim($str, '/');
$str = preg_replace('~(<a href="https?://vine.co)/v/(.*)" target="_blank">(https?://vine.co)/v/(.*)<\/a>~', $drc_embed_vine, $str);
```

**Tried something different**
Just messing around I gave this a shot

```
$str = $this->post['message'];
$str = rtrim($str, '/');

$this->post['message'] = $str;
```

So the post is

```
<a href="http://vine.co/v/iF20jKHvnqg/" target="_blank">http://vine.co/v/iF20jKHvnqg/</a>
```

and the `rtrim` had no effect =/

but if I change

```
$this->post['message'] = $str;
```

to

```
$this->post['message'] = test;
```

every post turns to `TEST` so I don't see why the rtrim has no effect =/

**update for clearity**

```
$this->post['message'] = 'Check out this vine <a href="http://vine.co/v/iF20jKHvnqg/" target="_blank">http://vine.co/v/iF20jKHvnqg/</a>';
$drc_embed_vine =  '<iframe src="https://vine.co/v/$2/embed/simple" width="480" height="480" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
$str = $this->post['message'];
$str = rtrim($str, '/');
$str = preg_replace('~(<a href="https?://vine.co)/v/(.*)" target="_blank">(https?://vine.co)/v/(.*)<\/a>~', $drc_embed_vine, $str);
```

**WORKING UPDATE!**

After Richards answer I toyed with the plugin a bit and came up with

```
$drc_embed_vine =  '<iframe src="https://vine.co/v/$2/embed/simple" width="480" height="480" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
$this->post['message'] = preg_replace('+/(["<])+', '$1', $this->post['message']);
$this->post['message'] = preg_replace('~(<a href="https?://vine.co)/v/(.*)" target="_blank">(https?://vine.co)/v/(.*)<\/a>~', $drc_embed_vine, $this->post['message']);
```

THIS WORKS! =) but is it the most efficient way...?

Comment: Can you create simpler example without all the talks what else doesn't work? I don't see where the $this->post['message'] gets converted. rtrim obviously wouldn't work, if the variable ends with </a>.

Comment: I'll add something to the OP so its formatted better, what more do you need?

Comment: Added a little example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the example bellow. I think your question is overcomplicated and I don't see the code that it's handling the replacement of of the $post->['message'], or generating the link for the iframe.

But I've tried to get an example as simple as possible to mimic the problem, that you're trying to solve

```
// input
$user = 'Check out this vine https://vine.co/v/iF20jKHvnqg/';
$after = 'Check out this vine <a href="https://vine.co/v/iF20jKHvnqg/" target="_blank">https://vine.co/v/iF20jKHvnqg/</a>';

// todo
$trim_user = rtrim($user, '/');
$trim_after = preg_replace('+/(["<])+', '$1', $after);

// output
echo "trim_user $trim_user\n";
echo "trim_after $trim_after\n";
```

so there are 2 inputs that you can have - the original message from user in $user or the replaced text with HTML links in $after.

Then on the $user, I'm just testing the rtrim, which works.

On the $after, I need to replace all occurence of / before " or <. It's because of quotes "" in  and closing tag . I'm replacing both with one regular expression.

See the parameters. 1st is regular expression to match the pattern, 2nd is replacement for the matched pattern, I'm skipping the slash / and using only the second part that I need to keep in.

[] square brackets in regexp means group of characters - like [abc] is any character of the a, b or c. If there's - it's a range. Like [a-z] is anything between a and z.

() brackets signifies a group, that will be stored in $1, $2, $3 based on the order of the group. In this case there's only 1 group, so I'm referring it as $1.

In another words / and any character from " and < will be replaced by the "clipboard" $1. That's again either " or <.

Last thing, I'm writing the output to the console.

```
trim_user Check out this vine https://vine.co/v/iF20jKHvnqg
trim_after Check out this vine <a href="https://vine.co/v/iF20jKHvnqg" target="_blank">https://vine.co/v/iF20jKHvnqg</a>
```

**Edited based on example**

You can avoid capturing the / by [^/]* instead of .* in the ().

```
class Example
{

    public function run()
    {
        $this->post['message'] = 'Check out this vine <a href="http://vine.co/v/iF20jKHvnqg/" target="_blank">http://vine.co/v/iF20jKHvnqg/</a>';
        $drc_embed_vine = '<iframe src="https://vine.co/v/$2/embed/simple" width="480" height="480" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
        $str = $this->post['message'];
        $str = rtrim($str, '/');
        $str = preg_replace('~(<a href="https?://vine.co)/v/([^/]*)/?" target="_blank">(https?://vine.co)/v/(.*)<\/a>~', $drc_embed_vine, $str);

        echo $str;
    }
}

$example = new Example();
$example->run();
```

Comment: ahh I get what you mean about the post, I use a CMS, vBulletin to be exact, `$this->post['message']` is just equal to what ever the user posts, got to finish reading your post still though =)

Comment: This wasn't a direct answer, but I got results =) Let me paly around with it really quick and I'll post back to update you, THANK YOU!

Comment: See the answer again after the bold Edited headline.

Comment: lol, that was before your edit which confused me more lol, let me toy with this really fast, thank you so much for the help!  Ill let you know what I end up with =)

Comment: added a working update to the OP, now I'm going to try omitting the / how you were talking about in your edit =)

Comment: omitting the / in the replace still seemed to cause conflicts since the iframe adds /embed.... some links ended up with //embed which caused an error.   I will be sticking with `$this->post['message'] = preg_replace('+/(["<])+', '$1', $this->post['message']);` for the simple reason it removes the trailing slash from EVERY link and in the long run this will be more useful for what Im working on, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$str = $this->post['message'];
$str = rtrim($str, '/');
```

Comment: seems like it should work, based on this answer I tried `$drc_embed_vine =  '<iframe src="https://vine.co/v/$2/embed/simple" width="480" height="480" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
    $str = $this->post['message'];
    $str = rtrim($str, '/');
    $str = preg_replace('~(<a href="https?://vine.co)/v/(.*)" target="_blank">(https?://vine.co)/v(.*)/<\/a>~', $drc_embed_vine, $str);` but it didn't work =/

Comment: I'll be adding things I attempt to the OP so it's structured better =)